# How to do calculations price calculation based on time and wage

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out final price based on wage multiplied by hours.

Here is my code
Why if the hours are 02:30:00 and the wage: $14 is my total 2?

```
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.Parse("02:30:00"); 
int wage = 14;
var result = (duration.Hours + (duration.Minutes / 60) * wage);
```

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. I've edited post's sample to show one option - at the same time it gets clear that totally unrelated [tag:model-view-controller] was not called for on the post at all ([tag:asp.net-mvc] may be a bit better, but not really needed).

Comment: Side note: one of standard duplicates for similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288904/division-returns-zero answers  your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the expression is actually evaluated as:

```
duration.Hours + ((duration.Minutes / 60) * cleaner.Price)
```

Second, you are doing integer division, so 30/60 will result in 0, leaving you with the value 2 i.e. the Hours part.

To fix the issue, you can do something like the below:

```
(duration.Hours + ((decimal)duration.Minutes / 60)) * 14;
```

Alternatively, you can skip this component-wise calculation, and just use the `TotalHours` property instead:

```
duration.TotalHours * 14
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks you!