# Assigning float with equation including ints

Tags: c#, math

```
score = houseWithHospitalCount/houseCount * houseCount;
```

score is a float and the rest are int.

when houseWithHospitalCount is less than houseCount score always returns 0

example: 2 = 2/2 * 2

example: 0 = 1/2 * 2

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this question, answered here:
[Division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288904/division-returns-zero)

From looking at that post, it appears you would need to use decimal literals for your ints to be interpreted as decimals and the division to not return zero.